# Game has random timings for hard lags

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, lag, chipmunk

So we've built a game where the player is jumping (on-tap) and needs to go thru moving obstacles (from the right to the left and vice versa) without hitting them.

We had everything clear and no lags and lately we've started to see some random "lags attacks", so you can jump like 500 times without any lags, while sometimes you can start the game and experience lags straight away.

I'm assuming that this has nothing to do with how we draw our obstacles nor with how we handle the graphics overall but with some background process going on.

Language and Engine: Objective-C, Cocos2d with Chipmunk.

Currently running the game thru: TestFlight.

Tested devices: 3 different iPhone's 5

EDIT:
So we've tried disabling all the external libraries and SDK's, Lags are still there.

Comment: Can you show a code snippet of your update method ?
can you try disabling all the ads and extra libraries and see if it reproduces ?

Comment: Ok so this is the tick method, where's the actual update method ?(the one with cocos2d updating the chipmunk world objects usually calls `cpSpaceStep`) ?

If they're different this might be the problem !

Comment: It's just calling: `tick>> - (void)update:(CCTime)delta
{
    [[GameController sharedGameController] tick:delta];
}` We are using the `CCPhysicsNode` where you don't need to call the `cpSpaceStep` on your own.

Comment: Hmmm I understand, it could be something with the while loops, is it possible to show the contents of the `generateNextObstaclesLine`, `createSuitIfNeeded` and `generateNextClouds` ?

Comment: I don't believe this is the reason. Like i noticed in the original post - The game isn't lagging all the time, it just lags randomly, so there is no problems in objects drawing. Sometimes you can play for like 3-5 minutes and there is no lag, sometimes you just see it straight from the 1st second.

Comment: You're making conclusions without knowing what the bug is, to you it seems random, but in reality it probably isn't, so you should start debugging by disabling your code, and start enabling it back part by part until the issue starts reproducing, but my two cents is that you should avoid having while loops (you have two while loops that almost do the same thing) and keep the code in your tick method to a minimum (keep in mind that this fires 60 times a second)

Comment: Thank you Mostafa, we will check all these things you wrote about and get back with an update.

Comment: do you apply delta time to physics step method? You may want to not do that, check my blog for an article about delta time

Comment: Do you have any CCLogs you are accidently printing out in a for loop?  Printing out a ton of log statements might slow things down a bit.

Comment: @PWiggin we had a settings button that may effected this, but no more we've delete it 2 days ago. No logs are shown in-game besides of the score which is changing every seconds accordingly - but we also disabled score updates to check if this cause the problem and nope, it's not the reason.